# fiegnclient does not recognise server.servlet.context-path mentioned in spring boot application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I am using feign client to call api of another microservices where I have mention `server.servlet.context-path ="some value"` and `spring.application.name="app name"` but while using it in feign client I am not getting complete url with context path.How should I mention `spring.application.name` so that it will give complete url of the service

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem? For example, how you configure feign, which URL do you get, which do you expect?